# how to create anonymous class with interface in C#

Tags: c#

as all of you know that there is new concept in C# 3.5 i.e. Anonymous type. how to create an anonymous type which implements one interface. Actually while writing UT for my component and also to improve the line coverage,i need this.

Kindly help me on this.

Comment: Anonymouse types cannot implement interfaces. What is it that you're trying to achieve? What is the underlying requirement?

Answer (score 4):

C# doesn't support creating anonymous types that implement an interface. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx):

> Anonymous types are class types that
>   consist of one or more public
>   read-only properties. No other kinds
>   of class members such as methods or
>   events are allowed. An anonymous type
>   cannot be cast to any interface or
>   type except for object.

You should probably define a new concrete type instead of using an anonymous type so that you can implement the interface you need.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are looking for a mocking framework like MOQ: http://code.google.com/p/moq/

It doesn't leverage Anonymous Types - these are very different java's version

Comment: This was going to be my comment it sounds as though the OP is actually interested in a mocking framework.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to have an annonymous type implement an interface. Since annonymous types are data only, this looks like you want to implement a data-only interface to me. I do consider this a bad design. You should rather create a DTO (Data-Transfer-Object, a class with just data).

However, if you really need the annonymous type to implement an interface, use [duck-typing](http://www.deftflux.net/blog/page/Duck-Typing-Project.aspx)